# multiple definition of a const int

Tags: int, constants

I have a header file `A.h` in which i define a `const int ID = 4;`. I have included this header file in to C files `A.c` and `main.c`. I have used header guards `#ifndef A_H #define   A_H` etc. But I get the error `multiple definition of ID` when I try to compile the code.
I read somewhere that this can, in most cases, be avoided by using `#pragma once` but I still get the error.
My question is that how can I define variables in C? Should I have to move definition of ID to C file but then I have to declare it in every file I use? Or using `extern` the only way in this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `extern` is the only solution. `pragma` or include guards guard against multiple inclusion in the same translation unit, this is a multiple definition error.

Answer (score 2):

In C you are only allowed to have a single definition per object. Include guards and similar don't help on this if you have multiple `.o` files (compilation units). Each of them has a copy, which is not allowed.

If you don't need the address of that object and you are only interested in its constant value you can replace it by

```
enum { ID = 4 };
```

This defines a named value `ID` of type `int` that you easily can put in a header file.